How do I turn off tag highlighting while editing xml files in visual studio?
Maybe I'm just searching with the wrong words and terms, but I can't find out how to turn this feature off, or at the very least reduce the intensity of the selection style
enter image description here
In the image above, any time I have a tag selected or I'm editing something, the large black background blocks a lot of what I see. It's hard to select the text because I can't see where the cursor is. It's a real pain in my productivity and I'd like to fix it.
I'm using the "Solarized" theme in Visual Studio, which for all I know may be the root cause. Any clues on how to fix this would be appreciated.
I searched for "highlight" and "matching" options under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> XML and a few other places but nothing I've toggled seems to work. I also looked under Environment -> Fonts and Colors and haven't found a font style that matches my problem

Adjusting Highlight Colors in Visual Studio
Go to Tools -> Options.
expand the Environment section->Click on Fonts and Colors.
In the Show settings for: dropdown, select Text Editor.
You could set Plain Text Item foreground to Red. (or other contrasting colors)
Look for display items that are related to highlighting and selection.
The most relevant items for your issue could be:
Highlighted Reference
Highlighted Written Reference
Highlighted Definition
Selected Text
Click on each relevant item and adjust the Item background and Item foreground colors
Click OK to apply the changes.
My result:


Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. In the Show settings for dropdown, select Text Editor. Scroll down in the Display items list to find Selected Text. Try choosing another color!
You can also try changing the color of Highlighted Reference, you can find it always under Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors.

Ctrl+Shift+P then >preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON),
in your workspace create a new .json file "settings.json" and put this file inside .vscode folder
settings.json:
{
    "editor.matchBrackets": "never",
    "editor.renderLineHighlight": "none",
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false
}

Reload window if you didn't see any change.
